# How can I display an endless loop of images via Google Cast?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm just getting started with a simple sender app and the default media receiver. Is it possible to either:

a. send a list of images that Chromecast will loop over

b. send a single url that Chromecast will refresh on an interval, letting the server "cycle" the images through

I'd want this to continue without the sender application needing to be open. I was hoping to not have to create a custom media receiver, as I'm assuming I'd be able to do what I want to do. It seems like I'd have to implement a lot of boilerplate and register the custom application just for some fairly simple functionality.

Comment: B would be pretty easy. Just setup a javascript carousel at a URL and point the chromecast there.

Comment: @dcclassics I'm not sure what you mean--I didn't think that you can point the chromecast at just a web page (according to https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media).

Comment: you are right.  My thinking was flawed.  I use "cast this tab" option, which is not an effective solution for you.  You have to have a host chrome browser to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but you need to write your own receiver to do that; the Default/Styled receivers that are available for you do not do what you have in mind.